# Download the springframework source code import idea success，create test module, dependency not working

Tags: java, spring, gradle

download spring framework source code from github. i create test module. 
The configuration file has been modified，
`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'io.spring.asciidoctor'
version '5.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile(project(":spring-beans"))
    compile(project(":spring-core"))
    compile(project(":spring-context"))
    compile(project(":spring-aop"))
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

then i create test java source file, use `@Autowired` Annotation
but its not work：

[image]

What's wrong？

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to compile relative projects but those don't exist. You need to refer to those artifacts by their group and version similar to how you're doing with JUnit 4.12.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.2.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: not work.
I created the test module，not Spring-test module